# English dictionary in readable format (text or xml)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am hoping to find a **downloadable (free or paid) English dictionary** preferably from Oxford, Cambridge, Webster in text or XML format to do some NLP.

I hope that each entry has

- a full part of speech,
- pronunciation,
- morphology in case of verb and noun
- multiple sense/definition entries

such as in the following page http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/side.

The actual text of the definition is not important. What I need most is the part of speech, pronunciation, morphology, order of definition entries.

**Also wondering**: what does the Stanford NLP toolkit use as lexical resources when it does POS tagging?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794454/where-can-i-obtain-an-english-dictionary-with-structured-data) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/where-can-i-obtain-an-english-dictionary-with-structured-data) are the similar questions. In summary:

1. [Part-of speech dictionary](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpos.html) - unfortunately, with quite narrow tag set.
2. [Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict)
3. Multiple senses - [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)

Morphological dictionary can be found in [FreeLing](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=23&Itemid=58) distribution - see data/en/dicc.src. Btw, there are also senses and phonetic dictionaries.

About Stanford POS tagger: they use [Penn treebank](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/links/statnlp.html#Treebanks), [proof](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#models)

Comment: Thanks a lot! [1] seems to need some proof reading. I didn't know that Stanford tagger uses POS lexical resources not built by dictionary. Nevertheless, this is great.

Comment: cool! I don't find the file data/en/dicc.src in FreeLing. has it moved?